# laravel: get name of active log at runtime

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to know the name of the current log in an app Laravel 5.

Try search for this on `Iluminate\Log\Writer`.

Only see $path var on call to some functions, but I don't understand how to get this value.

Basically, I need to compress the file and send it if the app gets some exceptions. For this, I need to know the name of active log.

My app conf log for daily rotation and see name of logs such `laravel-2016-04-29.log`

I know the name using PHP, but I imagine it is possible to know using the Log class itself.

The best I've thought

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
...

$carbon = new Carbon();
$log    = storage_path().'/logs/laravel-'.$carbon->toDateString().'.log';
```

I think there is a better way

Answer (score 0):

I happened to dig a little bit into Laravel logging a few days ago and possibly have a solution for you.

```
Log::info('abc');

foreach (Log::getMonolog()->getHandlers() as $handler) {
    $stream = $handler->getStream();

    if ($stream) {
        $meta = stream_get_meta_data($stream);
        echo $meta['uri'] . "<br/>";
    }
}
```

This will output paths of log files that have been written to.
Otherwise `getStream()` will return `null` and therefore path cannot be extracted so easily. It is stored in `url` property of `Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler`, unfortunately protected, therefore you would need to extend this class to get the path.

Comment: The route not problem. You get rute easy with `storage_path().'/logs/'`. It's name. Name is logical if not made any modification. laravel-DATETIME.log. DATETIME it's on local date format.